# Posting images/emotions to Facebook status

Tags: facebook

I am trying to post images/emotions to a users status. Here is an app that does it: http://apps.facebook.com/status-emoticon/

I've viewed the JS source and I'm cofused, it seems to be sending some sort of code as a message and facebook is turning that code into an image.

Any ideas?

Comment: This post seems to have some in also... 

http://www.facebook.com/niwenwoda?v=wall&story_fbid=144242572266348

No frigging idea how people are doing it. Have seen comments of status's and status updates containing them.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload an image to FB you have to encode it in the body of your HTTP request. I did something like this recently when messing around with the API, check out this project:

https://github.com/abrady/gappengine/tree/master/fb06_canvas

It is a canvas that lets you grab photos from your friend's albums and upload them into an album of your choice. (in particular, look at the function graph_put_file in fb06_canvas.py)